# How to scale up an Zend Framework Application that uses Zend_Search_Lucene

Tags: zend-framework, lucene, scalability, nfs, zend-search-lucene

I've recently released an ZF app to production environment, and I'm getting some troubles because this app is running in three different instances behind a load balancer.

These three app instances are sharing the same lucene indexes through NFS. I've just realized NFS is discouraged by [Zend Framework documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.index-creation.html#zend.search.lucene.index-creation.limitations.filesystems).

How should I deploy my app?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the easiest solution to this, if you're using the index ONLY to search, would be to copy the index and give each app its own copy to query.

If your app IS editing the index then you have a harder problem to solve. You'll more than likely have to choose a different search/index method besides Zend Lucene. You could use the Java Lucene instead, although I don't know if there's a PHP API for it.

I'm at a loss at what else you could do. I hope someone comes up with a crafty solution to this. Sounds like an interesting problem.